# Android Memory leaks on Orientation change

Tags: android, memory, orientation

I have made a simple Android test App. There is only one Activity and this Activity has only one TextView with it's text set to Hallo World.

Now when i change the orientation on my physical Device and check the Profiler in Android Studio 3.5 the Memory usage goes up **2 Mega every time i turn my Device.**
Normally nobody turns the orientation so many times, but the Memory usage in this case should remain pretty the same.

Can somebody please give me a idea why this happens ?
Sorry for my english, hope you understand my question and Thank you for your Time.

Answer (score 0):

What does orientation change entail? If you read android lifecycle documentation, you clearly see the OS recreates the activity after destroying the first instance. So depending what activity contains, redrawing everything is expensive. That's why we have to be careful on what to do when the user changes orientation.

Comment: The Activity contains nothing that a simple TextView. The Problem was that the GC only frees Memory after a long time, but if the App has no Memory leaks then you will see that when you for example switch to another App and then returns back to your App and check the Profiler then you will see that all Memory becomes free again if you really don't have Memory leaks.